# How to handle different android UI's

Tags: android

I recently ran into a problem with my app, On most android phones I have encountered, the UI seems to be mostly light colored.  Now though, it seems phones are making a switch over to a darker UI(droid x).  Now I found this to be a problem for instance with spinners.  I have not set a font color on my spinner, but it gets defaulted to black on all the UI's I have tested on, making it harder to read on the darker UI's.  What is the best way to handle this?  Pick a neutral color? Design for each UI?  Or is there a way to set the font color so the phone's UI can pick it up and set it to their default color?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. I have created a custom theme as a workaround.

See Comment #8 of this link
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5237